# Can anyone help me to find out what resources are suitable for practicing the TOEFL exam reading section?

Tags: resource-request, english, reading, test-preparation, toefl

I had the TOEFL exam a few days ago. I got 27 in writing, 25 in speaking, 26 in listening, and 17 in reading. Although I was able to read all the text, in the reading section, almost easily, the reading questions were very tough and the four-answer questions were similar to each other, and was pretty tough to take the right answer in 30 seconds for each question.

I believe, it is because the source that I was practicing on, was not commensurate with the rate of difficulty of the real exam. Even ETS website free practicing questions cannot demonstrate the difficulty of the real exams. I live in Iran and cannot purchase authentic practicing materials easily, although I can do that with extra effort. I just want to know if anyone can help me or introduce any other resources that represent the real difficulty of the questions in the exams. The TPO simulator provided by institutions in Iran does not represent the real difficulty of the exams in the limited time span. Any other suggestions will be welcomed.

Comment: Crossposted from: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/163631/can-anyone-help-me-to-find-out-what-resources-are-suitable-for-practicing-the-to

Answer (score 3):

There are a handful of practice exams online.

You can find 8 online reading tests here:

https://www.examenglish.com/TOEFL/toefl_reading.html

Another one here:

https://www.ets.org/toefl/test-takers/ibt/prepare/tests/reading

And if you scroll to the bottom of the second link, you can download additional tests as a pdf:

https://www.ets.org/s/toefl/pdf/reading_practice_sets.pdf

There are also equivalent practice tests for the other parts of the exam. Apart from just doing practice tests, I think general reading of advanced English texts should also help improve comprehension.